# How to preprocess time series data in Python for forecasting

Tags: python

I'm trying to prepare some time-series data (Forex) for forecasting in Python. The plan is to transform the time series into a 2-D Numpy array which will be passed to R as an R matrix via PypeR to train an ANFIS (adaptive neuro-fuzzy inference system) for forecasting. (The reasons why I would go through a process so convoluted are purely academic.) This would require that the first n columns be the last n data points and the (n + 1)th column be the current/predicted value.

Consider the following data points:

```
Date    AUD-USD
9/1/1999    0.6452
9/2/1999    0.6466
9/3/1999    0.6466
9/4/1999    0.6466
9/5/1999    0.6459
9/6/1999    0.6494
9/7/1999    0.6479
9/8/1999    0.653
9/9/1999    0.6512
```

For simplicity's sake, let's say that the five previous points will be used as inputs to predict the next data point. The array should, then, look something like:

```
            t - 5   t - 4   t - 3   t - 2   t - 1   t
9/6/1999    0.6452  0.6466  0.6466  0.6466  0.6459  0.6494
9/7/1999    0.6466  0.6466  0.6466  0.6459  0.6494  0.6479
9/8/1999    0.6466  0.6466  0.6459  0.6494  0.6479  0.653
9/9/1999    0.6466  0.6459  0.6494  0.6479  0.653   0.6512
```

minus the dates (just there for clarity's sake).

The question is this: Is there an existing Python function or library that will achieve the desired results? Or is this best done by hand through a series of loops? Additionally, is this process called something? I can't seem to Google a solution, so maybe I just don't know what word to call this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily construct your shifted array in one line. Here I used the range of integers to help you see what is going on - just replace `A` with your data.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(10)
cut = 6
B = np.array([A[k-cut:k] for k in xrange(cut,A.size)])
print B
```

Giving:

```
[[0 1 2 3 4 5]
 [1 2 3 4 5 6]
 [2 3 4 5 6 7]
 [3 4 5 6 7 8]]
```

For parsing the dates, try looking to pandas, it's an excellent library for data manipulation especially when dates are involved.

Comment: Awesome! So, that looks like a list comprehension to me. Is it? I haven't thought about using it like that, being a newcomer to Python and all.

Comment: That's all it is, along with a bit of slicing and a cast to a numpy array.